# Load components from an array of selectors

Tags: html, angular9

I have a list of components:

```
public entrys: any[] = [
'<component1></component1>',
'<component2></component2>',
'<component3></component3>'
];
```

I want to display the components of this array.

I tried this way but it didn't work:

```
<div *ngFor="let entry of entrys" [innerHTML]="entry"></div>
```

If it's a static HTML element (p, span) it works, but if it's a component I generated from angular CLI, it doesn't display the component on the screen.

I need to pass Input and Output in the selector, I tried using *ngComponentOutlet but I couldn't pass input and output.

Comment: You can't directly load Angular components via their selector strings as inner HTML because Angular components are not HTML elements. They get compiled to JavaScript by Angular's compiler and are instantiated dynamically.  There seem to be limitations with ngComponentOutlet that should not be a problem with the ComponentFactoryResolver, see below.

Comment: I googled a bit, maybe this helps. For dynamic component loading, you should use Angular's [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver). There are a few alternative ways to load components dynamically, start [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) and continue [here](https://shorturl.at/ryJQ3) and [here](https://dev.to/imbhanu47/dynamically-load-a-component-in-angular-based-on-event-b9).